# Naked function prototype declaration

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, reverse-engineering

I have tried to declare a naked function prototype in a header file:

```
inline __declspec(naked) void HookSoundFileSub_BZCC_Asm(char  *Src, int pedx, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6);
inline __declspec(naked) void __stdcall HookDamageSub_BZCC_Asm(DWORD * ecx, int ebp, int edi, int a4, long long *a5, int a6);
```

and I get this error (C2488) 'identifier' : 'naked' can only be applied to non-member function definitions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2488?view=msvc-160

some suggest ??

Thanks !!

Update:

I have already tried this code:

```
 void HookSoundFileSub_BZCC_Asm(char  *Src, int pedx, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6);
 void __stdcall HookDamageSub_BZCC_Asm(DWORD * ecx, int ebp, int edi, int a4, long long *a5, int a6);
```

with no compile errors, but the function crash.

If I use these functions in the main c++ file work correcly, but I like to insert it to a different c++ file module.

Comment: To my understanding, the naked attribute is relevant only to the definition of the function and cannot be specified in the function's prototype (/declaration). So this would generate a compiler error anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

The [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2488?view=msvc-160) you provided is clear enough.

> `naked` can only be applied to non-member function definitions, not
> declarations.

```
// C2488.cpp
// compile with: /c
// processor: x86
__declspec( naked ) void func();   // C2488  declaration, not definition
__declspec( naked ) void i;   // C2488  i is not a function

__declspec( naked ) void func() {}   // OK
```

Just put the `__declspec(naked)` from the function declaration to the definition.

NakedFunction.cpp:

```
__declspec(naked) void NakedFunction() { /* ... */ }
```

NakedFunction.h:

```
void NakedFunction();
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "NakedFunction.h"

int main()
{
    NakedFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine.

Comment: @user3449922 Just put the `__declspec(naked)` from the function declaration to the definition and everything works fine.

Comment: @user3449922 only use it when defining the function implementation. If you don't have control over that, because it's external, maybe a wrapper will work. Else you're just out of luck.